# DateFormat format.parse parse exception: Unparseable date

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting, simpledateformat

I am developing an android application and in one of the activities I am sorting a list of objects based on their date.

The problem I encounter is that the list of objects is being sorted in descending order for the German locale.

- if the locale is set to English(UK), the list is being sorted in an ascending order.
- if the locale is set German(Deutschland), the list is being sorted in a descending order.

In order to sort the list I am using the following:

```
           Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Object>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(MyPOJO obj1, MyPOJO obj2) {
                    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
                    Date date1, date2;

                    try {
                        date1 = format.parse(obj1.getPubDate());
                        date2 = format.parse(obj2.getPubDate());

                        return date1.compareTo(date2);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return 0;
                }
            });
```

For English, for an object I have the following date format:
Thu Aug 13 14:50:02 EEST 2015

and for German, the following:
Thu Aug 13 14:50:02 OESZ 2015

Do you know what might be the root cause of this behavior, and maybe a way to fix this?

Comment: first at all this will not even compile ... Object has no method getPubDate ... second ... even if it is hard to say what it returns other than it is a string ...  some string ... obviously if it is not in `"EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"` format format.parse will throw an exception and `compare` will return 0 ... **anyway, storing data as string in locale format is asking for a trouble**

Comment: I know, I have only used it in order to not use the one from my application. i will edit the question.

Comment: I agree with Selvin. Change `getPubDate()` to return a `DateTime` and have it represented as millis since epoch in your data store.

Comment: Your approaches worked. I have used the Date type instead of a String and there was no need anymore to parse the publish date.

Comment: (In German Thu should have been Don or such.)

Answer (score 0):

Using Strings to encode data is a code smell (it's called ["Primitive Obsession"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrimitiveObsession))

Change `getPubDate()` to return a Joda `DateTime` and have it represented as millis since epoch in your data store.